# Can someone tell me why my links aren't clickable when I have a div under it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a widget for my site that displays the author and their social links. It worked fine until I added the blurry background div in the mix. Something about it is not letting me click the links any more. I've tried adding z-index values, but that doesn't seem to help. Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krnak/) to see my problem. Below is the class in question...

```
.social_artist_image_wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    height:126px;
    width:580px;
    background-size:cover;
    opacity:0.3;

    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because element with `position:absolute` (or anything other than `static` are placed on top of `position:static` elements, unless they have a negative `z-index`.

Try putting `position:relative` on your inner area, plus a semi-transparent background colour: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krnak/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your div is not under it, it is on TOP of it. This is because you are using `position: absolute`. You probably can achieve what you are looking for with `position:relative`.

Comment: I found the problem. I just made `position:relative` to `.social_artist_text_wrapper` and it fixed it.

Comment: Great, save me the time of fiddling through the fiddle. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to have this:

```
.social_artist_text_wrapper a {
    color:#bbb;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;   
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

As others have said, it is because you absolutely positioned the background image. So in order to get the other elements to render in front of it you need to set the `z-index` property, which only works if the `position` property is something other than `static`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4dPN/).

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to the ".social_artist_image_wrapper" class

```
pointer-events:none;
```

***Lacks IE support so the positioning answers above may be better suited to your needs (unless you don't need to support IE8 or IE9)***